# Popup - code conversion to KV and PY files

Tags: python, kivy, popup

I would like to have code in KV and PY files that will display a YES/NO popup that I can instantiate anywhere in my app to pop the question.

Will a good kindly person help me to convert code I found on internet to KV file and PY file content.
I would like to be able to create an instance of this popup at any point in my app for display.

This is the sample I am working from:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ConfirmPopup>:
    cols:1
    Label:
        text: root.text
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '44sp'
        Button:
            text: 'Yes'
            on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer','yes')
        Button:
            text: 'No'
            on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', 'no')
''')

class ConfirmPopup(GridLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        super(ConfirmPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def on_answer(self, *args):
        pass    
    

class PopupTest(App):
    def build(self):
        content = ConfirmPopup(text='Do You Love Kivy?')
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        self.popup = Popup(title="Answer Question",
                            content=content,
                            size_hint=(None, None),
                            size=(480,400),
                            auto_dismiss= False)
        self.popup.open()
        
    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer):
        print "USER ANSWER: " , repr(answer)
        self.popup.dismiss()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopupTest().run()
```

I have tried the following:

KV file:

```
<YesNoPopup>:
    cols:1
    Label:
        text: root.text
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '44sp'
        Button:
            text: 'Yes'
            on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer','yes')
        Button:
            text: 'No'
            on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', 'no')
```

and  PY file:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class YesNoPopup(GridLayout):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        super(YesNoPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_answer(self, *args):
        pass


class PopupTest:
    def build(self):
        content = YesNoPopup(text='Are you sure?')
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        self.popup = Popup(title='PIN',
                       content=content,
                       size_hint=(0.6, 0.4),
                       auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.open()

    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer):
        print
        "USER ANSWER: ", repr(answer)
        self.dismiss()
```

Then in the App

```
   def pin_action(self):
        pop = PopupTest()
        pop.build()
```

But this only shows popup with Title and separator bar.

I will appreciate explanations of why you do what you do so that I as an 82 year old can learn and understand since my OO education is 22  years old and my Python Kivy is still in the learning stage.

Thanks a million

Comment: Unless your `kv` file is correctly named (See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#method-using-kv-file)), you must call `Builder.load_file()` to load the `kv` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by just calling the `_on_answer()` method directly from the `on_release:` of the `Button`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ConfirmPopup>:
    cols:1
    Label:
        text: root.text
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '44sp'
        Button:
            text: 'Yes'
            on_release: app._on_answer(root, 'yes')
        Button:
            text: 'No'
            on_release: app._on_answer(root, 'no')
''')


class ConfirmPopup(GridLayout):
    text = StringProperty()


class PopupTest(App):
    def build(self):
        content = ConfirmPopup(text='Do You Love Kivy?')
        self.popup = Popup(title="Answer Question",
                           content=content,
                           size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(480, 400),
                           auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.open()

    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer):
        print("USER ANSWER: ", repr(answer))
        self.popup.dismiss()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopupTest().run()
```

Comment: thanks but I am trying to modify the  code in the KV and PY files

Comment: The code you suggest I change is what I used as the basis for the code  I show in the KV and PY  text listings. That is the code I cant get working Many thanks

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Hi John Andeson  - appreciate your help - I amp trying to create a CLASS, using a KV and a PY file , that I can use to instantiate a popup for use in myapps. Unfortunately my skilss do not allow me at this moment to do so and therefore would apprecate if you can help me. NoObligation

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your question, the main problem is just that the `bind()` method creates a `WeakMethod` for the bound method. In your code:

```
   def pin_action(self):
        pop = PopupTest()
        pop.build()
```

An instance of `PopupTest` is created (which contains the bound `_on_answer()` method). But after the `build()` method of `PopupTest` is executed, the `Popup` is opened and the `pop` variable gets garbage collected. So the `_on_answer()` method is also garbage collected as a result. Since `bind()` creates a `WeakMethod`, there is no method left for the dispatched event to trigger.

There are two ways (that I know of) to fix this issue. One is to just modify the `pin_action()` method to retain a reference to `PopTest` so that is does not get garbage collected:

```
def pin_action(self):
    self.pop = PopupTest()
    self.pop.build()
```

Another way is to use `fbind()` instead of `bind()`, since `fbind()` keeps a reference to the bound method, so it cannot be garbage collected:

```
class PopupTest:
    def build(self):
        content = YesNoPopup(text='Are you sure?')
        # content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        content.fbind('on_answer', self._on_answer)
```

Comment: John thanks for your help so far., no  success Still only Title and Separator bar. My code now to execute:    def pin_action(self, _animal_code, _animal_name):
        self.pop = PopupTest()
        self.pop.build()
and my PY file looks like this:
class PopupTest:
    def build(self):
        content = YesNoPopup(content_text='Are you sure?')
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
        self.popup = Popup(title='PIN',
                       content=content,
                       size_hint=(0.6, 0.4),
                       auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.open()

Comment: So the question now goes back to how are you loading the `kv` file?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question.I have the Kivy code in a KV file  called popup.kv, my Puthon code in popup.PY and the     def pin_action(self, _animal_code, _animal_name):

        self.pop = PopupTest()
        self.pop.build()
code in ConfirmPopyup.py.  and then I run ConfirmPopup

Comment: In you `App` class `build()` method, add `Builder.load_file('popup.kv`)` as the first line in that method.

Comment: Thanks a million I have it working as you suggested

Comment: John, I was ecstatic avout your answer because I saw the full display but I have since seen that the BIND of the         content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)
is not doing what it should. The buttons blink but the of the key pressed text is not printed